# why Google Ads showing less mobile page speed score?

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, google-ads-api

I have a website which is having **85 (Mobile) and 95 (desktop)** page speed score on google page speed. But when I checked from Google ads landing page Mobile Page speed score its showing **1/10** and on few pages "-". What could be the possible reason for this issue?

Comment: for clarity - how are you checking from Google ads landing page? With Page Speed Insights you run a URL - there is no way to check it when navigating from another page. Do you mean that a landing page you have built for an Ad campaign is performing poorly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page speed score generates suggestions to make your page faster by recommending some of the best practises for specific page.
Where as testmysite is for entire content served from domain.
Also page speed data get updated every day where testmysite is for last month. So surely there will be difference. If you made performance improvement this month & can see changes in next month report.